# iPython/Jupyter %run magic appending .py to filename and causing error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm attempting to use the %run magic like so:

```
%run ../Tools/imports.ipynb
```

I am running this code in two notebooks in the same directory, however, in one of them I get this error:

```
ERROR:root:File `'../Tools/imports.ipynb.py'` not found.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here but I'm guessing there's some nuance as I did not write the first of the two notebooks. Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your question has some time but I just got the same problem.
Looks that when you run the `%run` command alone on a cell it will not do the append and the command will run successfully, but if in the same cell you add some other code, it will do the append and fails with the error you had.
To fix this you can run with dbutils

```
dbutils.notebook.run()
```

check more info here: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an issue with specifying the path.
I was also able to run this, without issue on an older version of JupyterLab as `%run -i '/shared_notebooks/0000.test_connection/Schedule Testing/1. file1.ipynb'`

I haven't found anything on google, but I happen to change it to `%run -i './1. file1.ipynb'` and it ran successfully.  :)

Answer (score -2):

Turns out it's a pathing problem. It seems IPython automatically appends .py to the end of the filename which was confusing me, but there's a seperate pathing error.
Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This is not helpful   XD